# TSP approach for Round Trip

Tags: algorithm, computer-science, genetic-algorithm, traveling-salesman

I have a problem to solve.
Below is the problem statement.

I am currently at a location **X**.
I have to start from X, and travel to these cities-A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V and then return back to **X**.

In what sequence i should cover these cities so that my round-trip distance is minimized?

Data: n x n matrix containing the distance across individual cities, and also distance between **X** and cities.

I know this is a **Traveling salesmen problem**,which is NP hard

I am looking for the **best** **approximation** technique/algorithm to use to solve this.

I have tried TSP Nearest Neighbours approach( which i consider as basic) and Clarke-Wright algorithm (not benificial.)

I'm looking for any leads/papers/open source projects(preferrably in python).

Note: Maximum cities <=50.I'm also looking for the methods which can give near to optimal result in least possible time.

Comment: Is that all the cities or can n be bigger?

Comment: @merlyn This is just for an example, maximum cities can be 50.

Comment: "I'm looking for any leads/papers/open source projects(preferrably in python)." asking for off-site resources is off-topic on StackOverflow. To discuss algorithms such as this (and if you can reword it to be on topic) you might be best posting on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) but be sure to check what is considered on topic there too

Comment: @Shubham 50 seems small enough that modern TSP solvers can simply find the optimal solution.

Comment: You will have to define what **best** is.

Comment: You've already tagged `Genetic Algorithm` so why not try to implement that? Biologically inspired algorithms are strong for TSP. You can also try `Particle Swarm Optimisation`.

Comment: Adding to above mentioned approaches, you can also try `Ant Colony Optimiszation`